# why does reverse(string[0:]) shows error in python , why can't i use this instead of reverse(string[1:]) + string[0]

Tags: python

please explain ,i am not able to understand
i have tried the code:

```
def reverse(string):
        if len(string) == 0:
            return string
        else:
            return reverse(string[0:])
st = str(input("Enter the string to be reversed: "))
print(reverse(st))
```

The above code gives me error as :

```
Enter the string to be reversed: samiksha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samiksha warang\Desktop\python\lab exps\exp3.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(reverse(st))
  File "C:\Users\samiksha warang\Desktop\python\lab exps\exp3.py", line 38, in reverse
    return reverse(string[0:])
  File "C:\Users\samiksha warang\Desktop\python\lab exps\exp3.py", line 38, in reverse
    return reverse(string[0:])
  File "C:\Users\samiksha warang\Desktop\python\lab exps\exp3.py", line 38, in reverse
    return reverse(string[0:])
  [Previous line repeated 1021 more times]
  File "C:\Users\samiksha warang\Desktop\python\lab exps\exp3.py", line 35, in reverse
    if len(string) == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: You're calling `reverse` in the method itself, so this is infinte loop, the last line shouldn't be indented

Comment: i did not understand . please elaborate

Comment: Your line `print(reverse(st))` is INSIDE the method, so when the method is near to end, you're just calling it again

Comment: even if i put the print statement outside,it still shows the same error

Comment: @azro the `print` doesn't even happen since it for sure returns something. The error is in the `return`, it's running that function every time it wants to return.

Comment: Got it .. `string[0:]` pass the same string, to not pass the first char it's `string[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recursive call merely repeats the previous call: you're not reducing the task to something smaller.  Thus, you have an infinite recursion.

Consider reversing the string "abc".  In the form that works, your recursion step is

```
return reverse("bc") + 'a'
```

This reduces the task from a 3-char string to a 2-char string.  THe next recursion will be

```
return reverse("c") + b
```

... which, when combined with the parent call, will eventually return "cba".

---

The failing version has a recursion step of

```
return reverse("abc")
```

In short, it calls itself with *exactly* the same input.  Thus, you get the same (lack of) processing on every call.  The input string never reaches the base case.